# Difference betweeen large object heap and Small object heap?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I'd like to clarify an issue with CLR managed heaps. There are 2 object managed heaps - Large Object Heap and Small Object Heap. I know that objects which size is more than 85kbytes will be putted to the LOH. SOH has 3 Generations (0,1,2). The LOH is a part of SOH(2nd generation objects) or a separate heap with objects which always are 2nd gen? The LOH should be cleared along with 2nd gen object of the SOH?

Comment: They are separate. The LOH is collected along with Gen2. Is that what you are clarifying?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Small Object Heap has generations that are checked from time to time. At the end of collection this heap is fragmented so it need to be compacte. If Large Objects were in this heep it would take long time for defragmentation. So they decided to have another heap Large Object Heap that will be exempt from this expensive operation of defragmenting.

There is really good book:
ftp://support.red-gate.com/ebooks/under-the-hood-of-net-memory-management-part1.pdf

page 55 LOH